# Python RandomForest sk-learn: stuck for a few hours, what is going on?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, curve-fitting

I got a large input vector. Currently, it has been stuck on running `calibrated_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)` for few hours. I don't know whether the program is dead or what. How do I print out some kind of progress while running inside the `calibrated_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)` function call?

```
clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', n_estimators = 350, max_features = 200,n_jobs=-1)
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clf, method='isotonic')
print "Here 1"
calibrated_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
print "Here 2"
```

x_train is a vector of size (51733, 250).
I am stucking on "Here 1" on the print output for few hours.

Comment: n_estimators=350 is a pretty large number. First try with 10, 20 and check if it still takes that much time

Comment: @VivekKumar : No it's not large at all. You can even use thousands of estimators without any problem. It depends mostly on the `max_depth` that you fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply set verbose to something higher than 0.

From

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
help(joblib.parallel)
```

> verbose: int, optional
>               The verbosity level: if non zero, progress messages are
>               printed. Above 50, the output is sent to stdout.
>               The frequency of the messages increases with the verbosity level.
>               If it more than 10, all iterations are reported.

`RandomForestClassifier` uses the `parallel` function from the `joblib` library.

```
import numpy
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

n = 1000

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=n)
X_train, y_train = X[0:n // 2], y[0:n // 2]
X_valid, y_valid = X[n // 2:], y[n // 2:]

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=350, verbose=100)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**Output**

> ```
> building tree 1 of 350
> [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
> building tree 2 of 350
> [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
> building tree 3 of 350
> [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   3 out of   3 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
> building tree 4 of 350
> [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   4 out of   4 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
> building tree 5 of 350
>
> [...]
>
> building tree 100 of 350
> building tree 101 of 350
> building tree 102 of 350
> building tree 103 of 350
> building tree 104 of 350
> [...]
> building tree 350 of 350
> [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 350 out of 350 | elapsed:    1.6s finished
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem comes from the number of tree you are using, here is a little trick to overcome it :

You can change the parameter `warm_start` to `True`. Do as follows :

```
# Start with 10 estimators
growing_rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, n_jobs=-1,  
                                    warm_start=True, random_state=42)
for i in range(35): # Let's suppose you want to add 340 more trees, to add up to 350
    growing_rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    growing_rf.n_estimators += 10
```

And at the end you can predict your test data with the Random Forest containing `350` trees.

```
growing_rf.predict_proba(X_test)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, this can be done by inserting a print out in the CalibratedClassifierCV source code, which is provided as part of sklearn, but it requires one to be quite familiar with the algorithm and implementations.

Since you don't need to know the exact progress of fitting, a work-around is to subclass ndarray and overload the indexing operator - I assume the x_train and y_train you pass in are ndarrays. Hence, every time the CalibratedClassifierCV fit method iterates through and tries to access the data, it will call your customized code. For example:

```
import numpy as np

class array_plus(np.ndarray):
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print("array_plus indexing operator called")
        return np.ndarray.__getitem__(self, idx)
```

And before passing those data to the fit method, you can "convert" (officially, Python doesn't support "casting") them into your new class:

```
new_x_train = array_plus(x_train)
new_y_train = array_plus(y_train)

calibrated_clf.fit(new_x_train, new_y_train)
```

You can even put a counter in the subclass to get a rough idea of where you are.